# How do I get these boxes to align in either jquery or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have boxes in a line, and I want it so when a new one is appended, it moves the others to the right and fits in on the left, and if the boxes overflow your screen they are simply hidden. I want to be able to keep appending so it needs to be  I know I could fiddle with absolute position and jquery - use hidden input with box count, calculate the screen width and define left or right positions, but to be honest I'd rather not: I'm sure there's a way of doing it with overflows but I cant get anything to work. I am open to adding divs / css etc. Many thanks,

HTML:

```
<div id="boxWrap">
    <div id="innerWrap">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function()  {

  var html = '<div class="box"></div>';
  $('#boxWrap').append(html);

});
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #333333;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#boxWrap {
    width: 100%;
     overflow-y: visible;
    height: 20px;

}
#innerWrap {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Edit:

```
<button>Append</button>
<div id="boxWrap">
    <div id="innerWrap"><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div></div>
</div>
<input id="count" value=0></input>




$('button').click(function(){

    var html = '<div class="box"></div>';
    $inWrap = $('#innerWrap');
    $inWrap.prepend(html);
    $lastBox = $inWrap.find('.box');

    var count = parseInt( $('#count').val(), 10 );
    count = count+1;

    $('#count').val(count.toString());
    var limit = $inWrap.width() / 110;
    if( 110*count >= $inWrap.width() ) {
        $lastBox.index(count-1).css( {"display": "none" }  );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the boxes to be added to the left of (before) the others, you'll want to use `prepend()`, you'll also want to call it on the parent of the boxes. You can keep your boxes on the same line by changing the `white-space` CSS property:

**jQuery**

```
var html = '<div class="box"></div>';
$('#innerWrap').prepend(html);
```

**CSS**

```
#innerWrap {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wLAwa/)

I'm not sure I've fully understood the question, but this is what I think you are looking for.

Comment: hi, thank you for your time. that's very close but how do I stop the box from displaying half? Also, the box widths get decreased a bit when the last one is added that can fit.

Comment: Hi there, that is just because of the white space between the `inline-block`s. You can comment out the space or just remove it: http://jsfiddle.net/wLAwa/1/

Comment: As for stopping only displaying half, you can alter the script to remove the last box if it overflows it's parent. Something like this would work: http://jsfiddle.net/wLAwa/2/

Comment: thank you :) saves me some js! i was going to use storage and arrays. you hero

Comment: Hi again, I've been thinking and these boxes will store data which I dont want to keep retrieving. Instead, I want to "display: none" the last element that is displayed when appending another so it could go items 1-4 visible, then 5-6 hidden, 7 visible. On click, 7 invisible, and 8 appended. I have edited my attempt but I can't get it to work! been over an hour now :(

Comment: You should ask ***another*** question. Remember to provide what you've tried.

Comment: done :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236073/how-do-i-hide-the-last-box-on-append if you can help!

Answer (score 0):

use `float:right`

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #333333;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
     float:right;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWVNu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using display table/table-cell which are perfect for filling a container with a random number of child without overflowing.

```
.box {
    background-color: #333333;
    display: table-cell;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
#boxWrap {
    width: 100%;

}
#innerWrap {
     width:100%;
    display:table;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle to explain](http://jsfiddle.net/tg24Z/)

You can click on "Click me" to add any number of box.

[Another fiddle with margin and min-width](http://jsfiddle.net/tg24Z/1/)

Comment: Hi, thank you but when the boxes extend over their limit, they display underneath. (keep clicking)

Comment: on the second example?

Comment: ah, apparently not :) but how do I stop display if the box isn't going to be fully displayed? i.e. only half the last one is?