# How do I hide the last box on append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<button>Append</button>
<div id="boxWrap">
    <div id="innerWrap"><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div></div>
</div>
<input id="count" value=0></input>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #333333;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#boxWrap {
    width: 100%;
     overflow-y: visible;
    height: 20px;

}
#innerWrap {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('button').click(function(){

    var html = '<div class="box"></div>';
    $inWrap = $('#innerWrap');
    $inWrap.prepend(html);
    $lastBox = $inWrap.find('.box');

    var count = parseInt( $('#count').val(), 10 );
    count = count+1;
    alert(count);
    $('#count').val(count.toString());
    var limit = $inWrap.width() / 110;
    if( 110*count >= $inWrap.width() ) {
        $lastBox.index(count-1).css( {"display": "none" }  );
    }

});
```

I want the last box displayed that can fit on the page to display: none when another is appended. Example:
4 boxes can fit,
click append
4th box hides
5 box takes its place
click append
5th box hides
6th box takes its place

The reason for this is they will eventually store data, and I want to be able to do the reverse when they are closed by the user. My trouble is trying to get the index of the boxes.

Thank you!

EDIT *********************************

Thankyou Jason P

For those who have similar aims, answer:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){

        var count = parseInt( $('#count').val(), 10 );
    count = count+1;
    var html = '<div class="box" id="' +count+ '"></div>';
    $inWrap = $('#innerWrap');
    $inWrap.prepend(html);
    $lastBox = $inWrap.find('.box');



    $('#count').val(count.toString());
    var limit = $inWrap.width() / 110;
    if( 110*count >= $inWrap.width() ) {
            $('#innerWrap .box:visible').last().hide();
        }

});
$('#btn2').click(function(){ // want the last one hidden to be first one back so it's the first one with display: none

    var count = parseInt( $('#count').val(), 10 ) - 1;
    $('#count').val(count.toString());
    $('#innerWrap .box:visible').last().hide();
    var limit = $inWrap.width() / 110;

    if(count > limit)
        $('#innerWrap .box:hidden').first().show();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find the last visible box like this:

```
$('#innerWrap .box:visible').last();
```

Comment: $('#innerWrap .box:visible').last().css({'display':'none'}); ?

Comment: From your question, I think you're probably looking for `$('#innerWrap .box:hidden').first()`

Comment: Just a quick note, you can use `hide()` and `show()`. Less verbose than setting the css.